# How to code saved comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to code, not exactly comments, but just something simple. A user types something in, and it *stays* on the website. Such as, if I typed 'hello', once I submitted the comment, if I refreshed the page I would still see my comment. It would also be helpful if there could be a field where the person could enter their name and their name would stay too. I've coded this but I can't figure out have the comments stay there

```css
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #23008B;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
 width:70px;
 background-color:#4000FF;
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:none;
 color:#ffffff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:2px;
 padding-top: 2px;
}

.list {
 font-family:garamond;
 color:#cc0000;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Insert Comments</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <div id="button">Add!</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $(".list").append("<div class = 'item'>" + toAdd + "</div>")
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'd just like to know what I'm missing and if there's anything in HTML or Jquery to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: what you are missing is server side code

Comment: You want that comments to be visible to other users?

Comment: You will want to pass to comment to a server-side page and store the comment on the server... Example `php` for the server-side language and a database... `mysql` maybe? using javascript or jQuery to append things is just client-side and will be forgotten once the page reloads/refresh.

Comment: You need some kind of storage like web storage or database.

Comment: learn php and mysql. to save the comments in a database and show them whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could persist your data using the browser's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).</s>

To share the same data amongst multiple users you can use a client-server architecture where any browser can act as a client and another single program as the server, the server will be the one responsible to handle the serving, persistence and update of data, in a fashion similar to this:

1. The client requests a webpage from the server.
2. The server populates the page with all user comments in its
       repository (databse, file, etc.) and sends it to the client.
3. If a user adds a comment, the client posts the comment to the
           server.
4. The server adds the comment to its repository and notifies all
       connected clients of the newly added message.

You can get started [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171203/207625).

Comment: Just a note on this, `localStorage` will only persist for the user that types the comment. It will not be visible to anyone else. Alternatively, there are some Backend-as-a-Service providers that will essentially help you abstract out the process of writing a service to store comments.